# Extjs : get modified records after store reconfigure

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I reconfigure my store and add new fields to it and then load its corresponding grid. I need to edit grid cells and save the whole modified grid rows in one step at the end.

The problem is that when I call this code, I get all rows in the grid even if I haven't edited any cell or row in the grid maybe because I have reconfigured the store.
But in fact nothing has been changed and new fields in the store are just for view.

How can I get the rows which their cell values has been changed ?

```
// returns all store records
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("documentgrid")[0].getStore().getModifiedRecords();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting all the records because I hadn't call commitChanges on the store after reconfigurer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not described quite clearly.
With a little guess,give you this answer,I hope it would help.

The getModifiedRecords() is not for that use.
Subscribe the store's "update" event instead.It can hook into the modification of model fields in the store.

Try code snippets:

```
{
    //your grid config goes here
    listeners:{
        update:function(me, record){
            //TODO save the modified record somewhere for your save button to pickup.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added this on my grid save button and nothing happened     getStore().on('update', function(this, record, operation, modifiedFieldNames, eOpts){
        });

Comment: First of all ,you should know this.The update event is published every time you edit your grid cell and your on update listener should be ready before cell editing.The saveButton handler is invoked after grid changing!Your listener has listened nothing.See my updated post.